# Haskell Type Error while using HTTP-Conduit

Tags: haskell, http-conduit

I am working on OAuth2 authentication for a Yesod application and  I am having a type error that I really really don't understand.  The code is broken at the moment, and I have a few `:: IO ()`'s and `undefined`s thrown around to help me isolate the type error, but the relevant code is:

```
getAccessToken :: Manager -> OAuth2 -> ExchangeToken -> IO (OAuth2Result Errors OAuth2Token)
getAccessToken manager oa code = do

  let (uri, defaultBody) = accessTokenUrl oa code
  let body = defaultBody <> [ ("client_id", TE.encodeUtf8 . oauthClientId $ oa )
                            , ("client_secret", TE.encodeUtf8 . oauthClientSecret $ oa)
                            , ("resource", TE.encodeUtf8 . oauthClientId $ oa)
                            ]

  response <- performOAuth2PostRequest manager oa uri body

  return undefined

performOAuth2PostRequest :: Manager -> OAuth2 -> URI -> PostBody -> IO (Response ByteString)
performOAuth2PostRequest manager oa uri body  = do
  defaultReq <- uriToRequest uri

  let addBasicAuth = applyBasicAuth (TE.encodeUtf8 . oauthClientId $ oa)
                                    (TE.encodeUtf8 . oauthClientSecret $ oa)

  let req = (addBasicAuth . updateRequestHeaders Nothing) defaultReq

  (httpLbs (urlEncodedBody body req) manager) :: IO (Response ByteString)
```

Notice that I am specifically setting the type of the `httpLbs (urlEnc...) manager` action as an `IO (Response ByteString)` using the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension.  Also, that line of code *should* be an IO action because it's being performed at the top level of an IO action.

In fact, I ran a GHCi session and did:

```
Network.OAuth.OAuth2.HttpClient Network.OAuth.OAuth2.Internal 
Network.HTTP.Conduit Data.Functor Prelude> :t httpLbs
httpLbs
  :: Control.Monad.IO.Class.MonadIO m =>
     Request
     -> Manager -> m (Response Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString)
```

Which confirms my understanding that `httpLbs` should yield a `MonadIO m => m (Response ByteString)`.

But here is the error I get:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘Response
                         Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString’
                 with ‘IO (Response ByteString)’
  Expected type: Manager -> IO (Response ByteString)
    Actual type: Manager
                 -> Response Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString
• The function ‘httpLbs’ is applied to two arguments,
  its type is ‘Request
               -> m1 (Response Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString)’,
  it is specialized to ‘Request
                        -> Manager -> Response Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString’
```

**Why is GHC specializing `m` to `Response` instead of `IO`?  How do I fix it?**

Comment: Based on what I can tell, the actual problem is the expected type is a strict `ByteString` while the actual type is a lazy `ByteString` (which the compiler helpfully indicates is a different type by printing it fully qualified). The error seems bogus, however, since there is no way to specialize the type of `httpLbs` to `Request -> Manager -> Response Lazy.ByteString` - even if you did set `m ~ Response` (which would give another very obvious error - `no instance for MonadIO Response`) then the actual instantiation would be `... -> Response (Response Lazy.ByteString)`.

Comment: Aside: the type annotation you gave in the final line doesn't make use of `ScopedTypeVariables` because `IO (Response ByteString)` doesn't contain any type variables; and it is also entirely superfluous, since the type signature on the function already gives the type.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't included your import statements, making it difficult to debug this. My best guess though is that you've imported `Network.HTTP.Simple`, which provides functions that do not require an explicit `Manager` argument. I'm guessing this from the error message providing the expected type:

```
Request -> m1 (Response Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString)
```

Solution: either change the import, or drop the `Manager` argument.